# Sharing a @State var Bool between 2 child Views in SwiftUI

Tags: swift, xcode, swiftui

I'm a designer who's trying to learn SwiftUI for fun and also to make sure I know a bit more what my developer's team needs from me.

And there's something very simple I just can't do!

As you can see from this piece of code below, I just want to show a text when the var showHello is true, and it's working nicely.

```
import SwiftUI

struct ContentView: View {

    @State var showHello = true

    var body: some View {

        VStack {
            Spacer()
            Button("Show Hello", action: { showHello.toggle() })
                .padding()
            Spacer()
            Text("This is your message:")
                .padding()
            if showHello == true {
                Text("Hello")
            } else {
                Text("Hello")
                    .opacity(0)
            }
            Spacer()
        }

    }

}

struct ContentView_Previews: PreviewProvider {
    static var previews: some View {
        ContentView()
    }
}
```

But when I want to do the exact same thing by using multiple views, it doesn't work!

```
// Parent file

import SwiftUI

struct ContentView: View {

    var body: some View {

        VStack {
            TopView()
            BottomView()
        }

    }

}

struct ContentView_Previews: PreviewProvider {
    static var previews: some View {
        ContentView()
    }
}
```

```
// Child file 1

import SwiftUI

struct TopView: View {

    @State var showHello = true

    var body: some View {

        Button("Show Hello", action: { showHello.toggle() })
            .padding()

    }

}

struct TopView_Previews: PreviewProvider {
    static var previews: some View {
        TopView()
    }
}
```

```
// Child file 2

import SwiftUI

struct BottomView: View {

    var body: some View {

        Text("This is your message:")
        if showHello == true {
            Text("Hello")
        } else {
            Text("Hello")
                .opacity(0)
        }

    }

}

struct BottomView_Previews: PreviewProvider {
    static var previews: some View {
        BottomView()
    }
}
```

And I know that we can't share a var from different views so I have spent hours on Internet to learn more about using @State/@Binding or @EnvironmentObject but all the examples are about sharing a var from a parent view to a child view but not between child views into a parent view.

Also, no matter what I'm doing, there's always an error from Xcode because something is missing somewhere!

I need your help, thanks in advance! :P

Comment: try something like this: add `@State var showHello = true` in `ContentView`, and put `@Binding var showHello: Bool` in your other views.
Then pass the `showHello` like this: `TopView(showHello: $showHello)` and `BottomView(showHello: $showHello)`.

Comment: Looks like you already have an answer, but as another note, you can shorten `if showHello == true` to just `if showHello`

Comment: I suggest you read-up on how to use `State` and `Binding`in SwiftUI. There is a good tutorial on this at: https://developer.apple.com/tutorials/swiftui/. These concepts are very important in SwiftUI. Happy coding.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

> I have spent hours on Internet to learn more about using @State/@Binding or @EnvironmentObject

So you are on the right path because you do need to use `@Binding`. Maybe you just had the wrong idea of how to connect the dots.

Basically you need the `@State` property wrapper in your parent or `ContentView` and since you want to share that same property in your child views and react to any mutation on it, you use the `@Binding` property wrapper in the child views.

So you would have something like this:

```
struct ContentView: View {
    @State var showHello = true

    var body: some View {
        VStack {
            TopView(showHello: $showHello)
            BottomView(showHello: showHello)
        }
    }
}

struct TopView: View {
    @Binding var showHello: Bool

    var body: some View {
        Button("Show Hello", action: { showHello.toggle() })
            .padding()
    }
}

struct BottomView: View {
    let showHello: Bool

    var body: some View {
        Text("This is your message:")
        Text("Hello")
            .opacity(showHello ? 1 : 0)
        }
    
}
```

I would recommend some other good resources for SwiftUI:

- [SwiftUI State Management](https://www.swiftbysundell.com/articles/swiftui-state-management-guide/)
- [@Binding](https://www.hackingwithswift.com/quick-start/swiftui/what-is-the-binding-property-wrapper)
- [SwiftUI Articles by John Sundell](https://www.swiftbysundell.com/discover/swiftui/)

Comment: Great answer, hope you don't mind I changed BottomView's bool to a let because its read only

Comment: @malhal I do not; thanks for the comment 

Comment: @NicolasElPapu @malhal Thanks a lot guys. I understand quite well how works `State/Binding` now and why I can use a `let` in the `BottomView`. Thanks again! But I still have an issue: Xcode wants something into `TopView()` and `BottomView()` in the `PreviewProvider` (at the bottom of the files). Do you know what I can add?

Comment: @Alexnnd if you click the error it would tell you why. You need to provide the properties to the View Class if you want to preview them, like if you were instantiating any class, for the case of the binding properties you could do `.constant(true)`. Also if you find answers helpful to your questions, feel free to upvote and mark as accepted too

Comment: @NicolasElPapu Thanks for your reply. Actually, I've just found the answer somewhere else. I'll add another comment and mark your proposition as the best answer. Thanks again! Too bad, I can't give your other comments a like. :P

Answer (score 0):

You don't need to use `@Binding` in this particular example since you are not changing the state of `showHello` in the child view. `@Binding` is for two-way data flow (i.e., from the parent to the child and vice versa). If your data flow is unidirectional (i.e., from the parent to the child), you can just use a simple `let` in the child view.

Also, instead of this:

```
if showHello == true {
    Text("Hello")
} else {
    Text("Hello")
        .opacity(0)
}
```

You should do this:

```
Text("Hello")
    .opacity(showHello ? 1 : 0)
```

The first way creates two different and separate `View`s whereas the second way creates a single `View` whose `opacity` modifier you change as needed. Not such a big deal with a simple `View` hierarchy like this, but once you start getting more complicated hierarchies it will help SwiftUI's view diffing and re-rendering. And it helps with animations since it's a property on one `View` that is changing rather than two `View`s switching out.

It's also just easier to read that way.

Comment: @Patrick Wynne Thanks! It seems better with just 2 lines.

Answer (score 0):

Alright, everything is working nicely. Thanks to all of you guys and especially to @NicolasElPapu.

Also, the solution is working with the simulator but not with the PreviewProviders. If you still have an error like I had, just update these pieces of code at the bottom.

```
struct TopView_Previews: PreviewProvider {
    static var previews: some View {
        TopView(showHello: .constant(true))
    }
}
```

```
struct BottomView_Previews: PreviewProvider {
    static var previews: some View {
        BottomView(showHello: true) // Or .constant(true) again if you're not using a let for the BottomView!
    }
}
```

Also, if you want to understand why you need to add a fake information into the PreviewProvider, here's the why: https://www.hackingwithswift.com/forums/swiftui/binding-variable-won-t-preview/10974

Thanks again guys!